# replacement for fanfold paper printouts

Tags: visualization

Back in university, we were able to print "unlimited" printouts on wide fanfold paper, (perhaps 128 characters wide or maybe more).  I could then unfurl the printed code out across the desks or the room and get a great overview of my code, draw circles and arrows and a paragraph on each one in the wide margin, see if this code matched that code, tweak variable names by seeing their brethren, etc, and I loved it.

Right now I'm using xcode for iOS programming, but the question comes up no matter what editor I've used: how can I get a good code overview that's bigger than my screen?

Answer (score 3):

Two simple things:

- only write functions that fit on one screen
- use a dual screen display (which is quite affordable nowadays)

The last time I needed a "fanfold paper printout" of some code was for a legacy function with several hundreds LOC. After refactoring this monster into small functions I never missed fanfold printouts again.

Comment: I generally do write short functions; but I often want to compare the functions to each other, or see if they should be re-ordered in a more meaningful way.  I have dual screens; maybe I should arrange them physically above one another...

Comment: @ThunderRabbit: perhaps you should try to write even shorter functions, like Bob Martin ;-)

Comment: @ThunderRabbit, have you ever seriously investigated Emacs, specifically electric-diff and the various split-screen commands?  It is IDEAL for comparing functions this way?

Comment: +1 for "only write functions that fit on one screen".  Unfortunately, most programmers these days seem to have been taught that run-on stream-of-consciousness code, with routines that go for hundreds of lines, is The Way To Go.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm  I've been using Emacs for years, though less and less for programming as I go.  I've not seen that particular mode (?) so thank you for mentioning it.  I'll try to see if it will play nicely with xcode.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit, M-x ediff, M-x ediff-buffers will get you started.  Once you are in ediff mode, | will flip between splitting the screen horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm the mode certainly seems useful!!  Thanks for mentioning it.